# best visualization way to show a PDF+CDF to non-math people

Tags: data-visualization, cumulative-distribution-function

EDIT: please ignore the actual formatting of the graph; it is meant as a demo and not "finalized".

We are struggling to find the best way to present CDFs to our customers. They can read PDFs, but they care about the information in CDFs because they want to know what percentage of others fall to the "left" or the "right" of them for several different metrics. We could just show them their percentile, but a graph would be nice.

Attached is a photo of a PDF and a CDF shown in blue and green respectively. We have found that most people do not understand the green graph. With the addition of the red annotated text, most understand it after studying it; but we are wondering if there is a more intuitive way to show people how to read this without giving such an explicit "training".

One cute idea I saw was here: http://www.amstat.org/publications/jse/v16n1/jernigan.html
but the problem with that is that it is now hard to visualize the PDF, i.e., it is hard to see the size of each bin.

So, do you know of any nice data visualization way of presenting a PDF and a CDF?

[image]

Comment: CDF's are often drawn as [stepped lines](https://www.google.com/search?q=cumulative+distribution+function&espv=2&biw=1280&bih=937&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=aFIdVfv_KNiBygTR1oGgCQ&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg). I might just suggest two charts instead of one, but there are some more obvious problems with the charts besides how to represent the ECDF and histogram, such as excessive font sizes, odd choice of bin locations on the X axis, gratuitous red annotations, and a misplaced title.

Comment: It might be useful to know that the blue graph is not really a PDF.  (The test is whether its area is unity.  This one's area is approximately 200.)  It is a frequency barchart.  The green plot would usually be known as an *empirical* cumulative distribution function, or ECDF.  These terms might help in a search for related graphical displays.

Comment: The blue graph is normalized to 1. The sum of the probability of being in each bin is 100%. Sorry for misnaming it!